# How to calculate-speed-distance-time in processing? Would love to have an example please

Tags: processing

This is how I did it, but I don't know how to use the formula. I am trying to create a fitness-pace-and-speed-calculator. But when it comes to the formula I am lost.

```java
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
a *= b;  // Sets 'a' to 10.
```

I know is suppose to be like this right? But I can't seem to understand the formula on how to calculate it.  If someone could please look over my code and see where and how to put the formula please?

```java
String myText = "Type"; 

int value = 0;
String myText1="TYPE", myText2="TYPE", myText3="TYPE", myText4="TYPE"; 

int selText=0; 

void setup() { 

  size(800, 800); 

  textSize(40);
} 

void draw() { 

  background(0, 187, 250); 
  textSize(40);
  fill(0);
  text("Pace and Speed Calculator", 150, 40);

  //outer box
  rect(50, 50, 700, 700);

  //top box
  fill(204);
  rect(75, 70, 650, 350);

  //bottom box
  fill(225);
  rect(75, 400, 650, 350); 

  //Initial data

  //time box
  textSize(40);
  fill(0);
  text("Time", 350, 125);

  //Ttile HOURS
  textSize(32);
  fill(0);
  text("Hours:", 125, 185);

  //Title Minutes
  textSize(32);
  fill(0);
  text("Minutes:", 125, 250);

  //Title Seconds
  textSize(32);
  fill(0);
  text("Seconds:", 125, 315);

  //Title Distance
  fill(0);
  text("Distance:", 125, 375);

  textSize(20);
  fill(0);
  text("metres(m)", 415, 375);

  //To tell user to double to enter
  textSize(25);
  text("Click the box to enter", 425, 250);

  //Speed box
  textSize(32);
  fill(0);
  text("Speed:", 125, 550);

  textSize(20);
  fill(0);
  text("kilometres per hour", 415, 550);

  //Pace box
  textSize(32);
  fill(0);
  text("Pace:", 125, 650);

  textSize(20);
  fill(0);
  text("min/km", 415, 650);

  //Button  
  fill(255);
  rect(550, 325, 150, 50);
  fill(0);
  textSize(32);
  text("Calculate", 555, 360);

  //time boxes 
  fill(255);

  rect(260, 150, 140, 50); 

  rect(260, 215, 140, 50);

  rect(260, 280, 140, 50);

  rect(260, 345, 140, 50);

  rect(260, 515, 140, 50);

  rect(260, 615, 140, 50);

  fill(255, 0, 0); 

  text(myText1, 260, 185); 

  text(myText2, 260, 250); 

  text(myText3, 260, 315); 

  text(myText4, 260, 380);

  //time boxes

  fill(0); 

  if (selText==1) { 

    myText1= myText; 

    text(myText1, 260, 185);
  } else if (selText==2) { 

    myText2= myText; 

    text(myText2, 260, 250);
  } else if (selText==3) { 

    myText3= myText; 

    text(myText3, 260, 315);
  } else if (selText==4) { 

    myText4= myText; 

    text(myText4, 260, 380);
  }
}

void mouseClicked() { 

  if (mouseX>260 && mouseX<500 && mouseY>170 && mouseY<200) { 

    myText = myText1; 

    selText = 1;
  } else if (mouseX>260 && mouseX<500 && mouseY>230 && mouseY<260) { 

    myText = myText2; 

    selText = 2;
  } else if (mouseX>260 && mouseX<500 && mouseY>270 && mouseY<320) { 

    myText = myText3; 

    selText = 3;
  } else if (mouseX>260 && mouseX<500 && mouseY>330 && mouseY<390) { 

    myText = myText4; 

    selText = 4;
  } else { 

    selText = 0;
  } 

  if (value == 0) {
    value = 255;
  } else {
    value = 0;
  }
}


void keyPressed() { 

  if (keyCode == BACKSPACE) { 

    if (myText.length() > 0) { 

      myText = myText.substring(0, myText.length()-1);
    }
  } else if (keyCode == DELETE) { 

    myText = "";
  } else if (keyCode != SHIFT && keyCode != CONTROL && keyCode != ALT) { 

    myText = myText + key;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fistly, `a *= b` is the same as `a = a*b`.

Your inputs are hours, minutes, seconds and distance (metres) and your outputs are speed (km/h) and pace(min/km) and the units are your formula.

So you are going to need values for the time in hours, time in minutes and the distance in kilometres.

```java
  float timeHours = hours + minutes/60 + seconds/3600;
  float timeMinutes = hours*60 + minutes + seconds/60;
  float distanceKM = distance/1000;

  // Speed = km/h
  float speed = distanceKM/timeHours;
  // Pace = min/km
  float pace = timeMinutes/distanceKM;
```

Comment: So i create a new tab? And insert the formula like this int a = myText1;?